# rows less than 5

Tags: r

i'm trying to find which simple events have a difference between the maximum and minimum of no more than 10.
the code i have is

```
sampleSpace <- combinayions(100,3,seq(1,100,by=1),repeats.allowed=FALSE)


diff <- sample_max - sample_min
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: What package does `permutations` come from?

Comment: @AllanCameron library(gtools)

Comment: Maybe this `diff[which(diff<=10)] -> diff2`

Answer (score 0):

The subset of `sampleSpace` where the difference between max and min in each row is given by:

```r
ss <- apply(sampleSpace, 1, function(x) abs(diff(range(x))) <= 10)
```

So you can do

```
sampleSpace[ss,]
```

to get just the rows meeting that criterion. There are 25,020 remaining rows. The first 30 are:

```r
sampleSpace[ss,]
#>          [,1] [,2] [,3]
#>     [1,]    1    2    3
#>     [2,]    1    2    4
#>     [3,]    1    2    5
#>     [4,]    1    2    6
#>     [5,]    1    2    7
#>     [6,]    1    2    8
#>     [7,]    1    2    9
#>     [8,]    1    2   10
#>     [9,]    1    2   11
#>    [10,]    1    3    2
#>    [11,]    1    3    4
#>    [12,]    1    3    5
#>    [13,]    1    3    6
#>    [14,]    1    3    7
#>    [15,]    1    3    8
#>    [16,]    1    3    9
#>    [17,]    1    3   10
#>    [18,]    1    3   11
#>    [19,]    1    4    2
#>    [20,]    1    4    3
#>    [21,]    1    4    5
#>    [22,]    1    4    6
#>    [23,]    1    4    7
#>    [24,]    1    4    8
#>    [25,]    1    4    9
#>    [26,]    1    4   10
#>    [27,]    1    4   11
#>    [28,]    1    5    2
#>    [29,]    1    5    3
#>    [30,]    1    5    4
```

Comment: i get a Kill signal (SIGKILL)
error for this

Comment: @mei is that perhaps related to resources? It takes a while to process all 2.9 million rows. Works fine on my machine (although takes a few seconds)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `which()`, as follows:

```
sampleSpace = sampleSpace[which(diff <= 10), ]
head(sampleSpace)
```

Here is the output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    4
[3,]    1    2    5
[4,]    1    2    6
[5,]    1    2    7
[6,]    1    2    8
```

Comment: i get subscript out of bounds for this

Comment: please, try again. i don't get any error message.. use `sampleSpace = sampleSpace[which(diff <= 10), ]`!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowRanges` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
m1 <- rowRanges(sampleSpace)
out <- sampleSpace[(m1[,2]- m1[,1]) <= 10,]
```